# Syncing contacts between Mac, Nokia E51 and iPod touch

Tags: sync, calendar, contacts

Currently I have all my contacts and calendar items in the cloud on my GMail account, but I have no way of syncing them between all three of my devices. How can I go about syncing them all together automatically, with the least amount of hassle.

I have thought about MobileMe, but it does not look like it supports S60 running on my Nokia E51. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/products/sync.html#p=default) to sync all of your devices together.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [NuevaSync](https://www.nuevasync.com/) for supporting your iPod and phone

Answer (score 1):

As a previous poster said, use http://nuevasync.com to turn your Google Contacts into an Microsoft Exchange service. Then connect the Nuevasync Service from your iPod Touch and your E51.

Your Mac is a different story. See also a question I have asked here:
[Google Contacts and Mac OS X Address Book](https://superuser.com/questions/825/google-contacts-and-mac-os-x-address-book)

Your best best is to enable Google Contacts sync form Mac Address Book and live with the limitations of that, unless someone comes up with something clever. Snow Leopard will enable you to hook up Nuevasync to the OS itself.