# Sync contacts between iPod Touch, Sony Ericcson k750i, Thunderbird (x2) and Gmail

Tags: sync, thunderbird, gmail, mobile-phone, ipod-touch

> **Related Question:**
>   [Syncing contacts between Mac, Nokia E51 and iPod Touch](https://superuser.com/questions/1894)

Is it possible for me to sync my contacts between:

- Gmail
- My iPod Touch (I've got an app to send free texts through webmail)
- Thunderbird on Windows
- Thunderbird on Linux
- Sony Ericcson k750i

I'm looking at using Google Contacts as the actual location of the contacts, which means I've got the iPod Touch and Gmail already synced using the instructions from Google.

I'd like it to be as automatic as possible for Gmail, Thunderbird, and the iPod Touch. However, my mobile phone network charges excessively for internet usage, so I'd rather the phone be a manual process.

The bulk of my contacts are currently stored on my k750i.

EDIT:

> The other question may be related, but it is not a dupe, whoever voted to close. Mac's default is not Thunderbird. And unlike the Nokia E51, the Sony Ericcson k750i is not a smartphone, and is not supported by google sync (the accepted answer on the other question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- k750: [Google SyncML](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/topic.py?topic=22181)
- iPod Touch: [Google Sync for iPhone](http://www.google.com/sync/iphone.html)
- Thunderbird: [Google Contacts addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/7307)

Notes:

- I think I have used addon for Thunderbird and that it worked very well. I'm not sure if it works well two way.
- Since iPod Touch is basically an iPhone with stripped GSM, I see no reason Google Sync for iPhone shouldn't work. I have no idea if it does work, though.
- I am a very happy user of Google Sync my on k750i.

Good luck!

And don't forget to backup your contacts on each device individually *before* attempting this! I speak from experience, you'll end up with duplicates and sometimes even messed up contacts; it's not because of what the services do, it's because you probably already have same contacts in multiple devices

Comment: Thanks that worked. Way ahead of you on the backups. Google Sync was pretty cool, it managed to realise they were the same despite having Full names on iPod/Thunderbird, and First Name + Last Initial on the Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Yuo can save the contacts from your Sony Ericsson phone using [Float's Mobile Engine](http://fma.sourceforge.net/index2.htm) (FMA); it saves them as CVS files, which you can just import into [Google Contacts](http://www.google.com/contacts) using the Import function. From there on, it's just a matter of removing or merging the duplicates and syncing them with your iPod Touch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've looked into this. Their site is so badly organised, I had to register, find a password (with no hints to it's location), and then search threads to get simple information. that its put me off. If they are so unhelpful, why should I use their software? (Not aimed at you, and sorry if it sounded like it, but I'm just explaining why I'm not upvoting this answer or marking it as accepted)

Comment: Sorry it didn't help you. The software is no longer actively developed, but it works. I use it with my SE W810, and it's ok. Here's the download link, if you want to give it a try: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fma/files/FMA%20%28Beta%29/FMA%202.1%20Beta%204/fma-2.1-beta-4-setup.exe/download. There's no password required, just download it and use it :).

Comment: By the way, It's no problem if you don't upvote, I just want to help you :).